# How to record query performance in Oracle

Tags: oracle, performance, query-performance

We have an Oracle DB with lots of tables and views (70k+) across several schemas, and on top of it several tens of "consumer views" in a schema where consuming applications can connect and select data.

The testing team and also the managers would like to have a record of what views are accessed, when, how long the query took and how many rows were returned. Basically when any of the consumer views gets touched by a SELECT query, the system should record the following information:

- the query itself (can be a simple select * from one view, or something much more complicated)
- timestamp when the query processing started
- timestamp when the query processing ended
- how many rows were returned

Maybe some other information will be required in the future but these are the most important ones. What is the easiest / most straightforward way to achieve this? I understand the solution would probably involve triggers, but I'm not sure where exactly can I get these pieces of information in the first place (or whether it's at all possible).

Thanks a lot for any advice!

Comment: The solution depends on what client app is being used to connect to db. For example, it you are using Sql*Plus, you can get this information by doing "set trace on" and/or "set time on", etc. before the query runs.

Comment: We would like to have a universal solution that can work for any client application. Otherwise we'd have to implement a separate solution for each application the clients might be using.

What we really want is to implement this in Oracle alone, so that it works regardless of the client app used.